# Converting a string with a time to the amount of milli seconds

Tags: java

I need to convert the following string to the amount of seconds
I tried to do this with the code below:

```
String sDuration = "00:00:24.20";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS");
videoLength = dateFormat.parse(sDuration);
Logger.debug("Duration: " + videoLength + " timestamp: " + videoLength.getTime());
```

But what I get as response is:

```
Duration: Thu Jan 01 00:00:24 GMT 1970 timestamp: -3575980
```

The first seems fine, but I need to .getTime() for my calculation and I get a negative number?
I expected to get something like 24200.

Comment: Messing with a date parser, which is instant-oriented, for time intervals is a very bad practice, prone to all kinds of unexpected errors. If you want library support, try JodaTime, I think it supports this use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely sure if `Date` is intended to be used for durations (rather points in time).

Here's an alternative approach though:

```
String[] hms = sDuration.split(":");

double sec = Integer.parseInt(hms[0]) * 3600
           + Integer.parseInt(hms[1]) * 60
           + Double.parseDouble(hms[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach:

```
String sDuration = "00:00:24.20";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS");
Date end = dateFormat.parse(sDuration);
Date start = dateFormat.parse("00:00:00.00");
System.out.println("Duration: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing some tests and the reason behind these is the time zone you are in.

If I do

```
Date begin = new Date().setTime(0);
System.out.println(begin);
```

I get this output :

Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970

So anything between 00:00::00 and 01:00:00 will have a negative number of milliseconds for my time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that SimpleDateFormat is **not** thread-safe, it should be called like this:

```
    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
    @Override protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() { return new SimpleDateFormat("format"); };
    @Override public void set(SimpleDateFormat value) { /*...*/ };
};
```

Comment: No worries, he is using local variables.